# How can I create an animated border around a website using the marquee tag?

Tags: html, css, marquee

https://www.awwwards.com/inspiration/gifs-and-marquee-animation-by-max-siedentopf

This is what I'd like to recreate. I'm new to coding.

To be honest the only part I can do is the bottom which is simple but I don't know how to use the marquee tag for the vertical texts as well as making it look seamless and also making it run " OPEN 24/7 " an infinite amount of times.

This is all I have at the moment:

```css
.open {
  bottom: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 70px;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<p>
      <marquee class="open" width="90%"> OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp; OPEN 24/7 &nbsp;</marquee>
    </p>
```

Comment: Note that [the marquee element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMarqueeElement) and may not be supported in newer browsers. Though the effect [can also be implemented with pure CSS](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2020/03/31/css-only-marquee-effect/), this is generally to be avoided due to [usability problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element#Usability_problems).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is [code](https://codepen.io/Knovour/pen/boJNPN) in the below.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: black;
font-size: 144px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.marquee {
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
max-width: 100%;
height: 200px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.track {
position: absolute;
white-space: nowrap;
will-change: transform;
animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
from { transform: translateX(0); }
to { transform: translateX(-50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
<div class="track">
<div class="content">Open 24/7 Open 24/7 Open 24/7 Open 24/7</div>
</div>
</div>
```